# want to change password for mysql root, but got error

Tags: mysql, macos

I install Mysql5 using macports. But when trying to create password for the root account, I got this error:

```
sh-3.2# /opt/local/lib/mysql5/bin/mysqladmin  -u root password 123456
/opt/local/lib/mysql5/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock' (61)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock' exists!
```

How to fix this?

Comment: You might want to check whether the service is actually running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if the mysql daemon is running

```
ps aux | grep mysqld
```

If it is you should see something like:

```
mysql    28290  1.1  2.7 340496 56812 ?        Sl   Jul31 348:27 /usr/libexec/mysqld --defaults-file=/etc/my.cnf --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --skip-locking --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

If you are lucky you will see the --socket argument specifying exactly where your socket file is located.  If it is somewhere different than the path your mysql client is looking for (/opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock), then you can specify it manually as one of the command line arguments.

Also, you should check to see if /etc/my.cnf exists and is setup properly, here is an example my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
user=mysql_owner
datadir=/path/to/datadir/mysql
socket=/path/to/datadir/mysql/mysql.sock
skip-innodb

[mysql.server]
user=mysql_owner
basedir=/path/to/datadir

[client]
user=mysql_owner
socket=/path/to/datadir/mysql/mysql.sock

[safe_mysqld]
err-log=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Hope this helps, fire away with questions if you are still having issues

Answer (score 0):

Check what is the default socket for your distribution. You can also try connectiong on TCP4 using:

```
/opt/local/lib/mysql5/bin/mysqladmin -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p secret
```

Or if you have found the path to your socket (in mysql's config file) you can use somthing like:

```
/opt/local/lib/mysql5/bin/mysqladmin --socket=/tmp/mysql.sock -u root -p secret
```

Comment: i got this error. /opt/local/lib/mysql5/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at '127.0.0.1' failed
error: 'Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 61'

Comment: You can check the logs of your MySQL server. Also check the config file, `my.cnf` for correct path names of log files and the socket.